# how to groupby statement in pandas other than crosstab

Tags: pandas, numpy, group-by, pandas-groupby

let say there is a dataframe

`df = pd.DataFrame( {'col1': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 'col2': ['x', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'y']} )`

I want to show this in a table whose index is `a` and column `x` is `2` and `y` is `1` just like in the 1st attached picture (https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtYIa.jpg).
I used crosstab but I am getting two separate rows like in the 2nd attached picture.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/GemfM.jpg)

Comment: check [rename_axis](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df = df.set_index('col1')
```

Here is the result:

```
     col2
col1    
a     x
a     x
a     y
b     y
b     y
```

Same as your first attached picture.